# MongoError : selector must be a valid JavaScript object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb driver for nodejs.

I am getting below error while updating a record.

> {"name":"MongoError","message":"selector must be a valid JavaScript
>   object","driver":true}

Here is my script :

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
      if (err) 
      {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
        return;
      }
    var collName = "bank";
    var SelectParas = {"name":"ABC"};
    var UpdateValues = {"name":"PQR"};

    db.collection(collName).update(collName,SelectParas,{$set:UpdateValues},function (err,numUpdated){
            if(err)
            {
            console.log('err');
            console.log(err);
            return; 
            }
            if(numUpdated) 
            {
             console.log('Updated Successfully %d document(s).', numUpdated);
            }
                db.close();

            });
});
```

I can write the below line in mongo console & it works.

```
db.bank.update({"name":"ABC"},{$set:{"name":"PQR"}})
```

Comment: Remove the `collName` from the `update()` method arguments list i.e. your operation should be `db.collection(collName).update(SelectParas,{$set:UpdateValues},function (err,numUpdated){ ... });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing collecion name i.e. a string as find query of the update. Need not pass collecton name there.

```
db.collection(collName).update(collName,SelectParas,{$set:UpdateValues},function (err,numUpdated) 
// collName need not pass in the update function.
```

Need to use

`db.collection(collName).update(SelectParas,{$set:UpdateValues},function (err,numUpdated)` instead.